# setTimeout wont work in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

So im going to do a loop (gif'ish) with canvas, that changes image in canvas every 70ms
ive tried plank javascript, but i gave up after 2 days and 5 coders had their finger in their mouth.
I have 10 images all named "ratasX" and id'd with number 1-10

Heres my script

```
$(document).ready (function () {
$("canvas").drawImage({
    source: "ratas1.jpg",
    x: 60, y: 60
});
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas2.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas3.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas4.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas5.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000)
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas6.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas7.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas8.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas9.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000);
$("canvas").clearCanvas();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: "ratas10.jpg",
        x: 60, y: 60
    });
}, 1000)
});
```

is missing cause this site ducks it up....
wait time is set to 1000ms in this example.
Im also using jcanavas

It hops straight to last picture

Comment: Classical question. setTimeout is not synchronous. It doesn't make your script sleep, it programs something to be executed in a certain amount of time and continues right away. See setInterval instead. Btw your slideshow would be a lot less dirty if it wasn't hard coded.

Comment: I think you want to use setInterval?

Comment: Well to make your code look better define the source in array and loop it through, currently this looks a lot of repetitive code. Head ratta leiutamist sulle :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like the below. I haven't tested this but its pretty straight forward.

Every 1 second the code will execute, clear the canvas and draw a new image starting with `rasta1.jpg` to `rasta10.jpg`. <s>with a random number between 1-10. e.g `rasta2.jpg`</s>.

**JQuery**

```
var count = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    $("canvas").clearCanvas();
    $("canvas").drawImage({
       source: "ratas"+ count +".jpg",
       x: 150, y: 150,
       scale: 0.5
    });

    if(count != 10){
        count++;
    }
    else {
        count = 1;
    }  
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is almost perfect!
Only thing is that its random, when it should be 1-10 and then again 1-10. but this is a good start. I just found out about setInterval

Comment: I've updated the code to loop though `rasta1.jpg` to `rasta10.jpg` then start from 1 again.

Answer (score 1):

I would read up on the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) function, it seems like you don't really understand what it's supposed to do. It sets functions to run asynchronously, so after `setTimeout()` is called, execution will proceed to the next step

For example:

```
console.log('1');
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('2');
}, 1000);
console.log('3');
```

will print:

```
1
3
2
```

That's because when you call `setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);` you're really saying, "In 1 second, run this method"

but the way you think it's working is: "Wait 1 second, then run this method." There's a subtle difference.

What you probably want is something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('1');
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('2');
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('3');
}, 3000);
```

which will print:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you run 10 commands that will all run after a 1000ms

---

You could simplify/correct this to

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var images = ['ratas1.jpg','ratas2.jpg','ratas3.jpg',
                  'ratas4.jpg','ratas5.jpg','ratas6.jpg',
                  'ratas7.jpg','ratas8.jpg','ratas9.jpg',
                  'ratas10.jpg'],
        length = images.length,
        current = 0;

     function draw(){
        $("canvas").clearCanvas();
        $("canvas").drawImage({
            source: images[current],
            x: 60, y: 60
        });
        current = (current+1) % length;
        setTimeout( draw, 1000);
     }
     draw();
});
```

This way your images can be any number and have any name..